# Sending mail to yahoo using php

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to send an email (with clickable link), I can receive the message but I can't click on the link it's like a text that you can't click on it !
**And I get this problem only with yahoo account I try it with gmail and it works fine!**
This is my php code:

```
$to  = 'test@example.com';//$email;

// subject
$subject = 'subject';//'Activation account';

// message
$message = '<html>
            <head>
              <title>Activation account</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <p>Thank you for subscribing to our site, please click on the link below to activate your account:</p>
            <a href="httm://www.google.com" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;display: inline-block;color: #FFFFFF;background-color: #8AC007;font-size: 15px;text-align: center;padding: 5px 16px;text-decoration: none;margin-left: 0;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 5px;border: 1px solid #8AC007;white-space: nowrap;">
                Activate my account
            </a> /*styled link is not working*/
            <br>        
            <a href="www.google.fr">google</a> /* even a simple link is not working*/
            </body>
            </html>';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: name <name@test.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: origin <contact@example.com>' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it... it seems that i must write the complete link with the 'http://' I dunno why only yahoo needs this format. it was working fine with gmail and hotmail.